# How to change my maintenance page?

Tags: theming, maintenance-mode

As the title explains, I want to make a custom maintenance page, different from the default one.

For that I've read this tutorial: [Theming the Drupal maintenance page](https://drupal.org/node/195435).

I copied the file /module/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php to my theme folder, changed it a little bit, and I enabled the `$conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'themeName';` line in settings.php; but I can't see the changes

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: no i didn't but i'm not using any cache system

Comment: Drupal has built-in caches. They must be cleared after any change.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: i'm using D7, and even when i cleared the cache nothing happened

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you,

Before site goes offline for maintenance mode, check the user who has permission to access the site during maintenance mode via **admin/people/permissions**
and check for this permission **Use the site in maintenance mode**. Default access will be given to the **admin**.

In Drupal 7, to create a custom maintenance page we have to override the default maintenance template file

We can do it by the following steps:

- Copy **maintenance-page.tpl.php** from modules/system/
- Paste it in **active theme** folder inside **templates** folder
  ie., sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/
- Make the changes in new maintenance template file.
- Clear the Drupal cache - configuration > performance > clear all caches

Note:

- If you want how to **Put Drupal 7 in Maintenance Mode**, you can go through this [link](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-put-drupal-7-in-maintenance-mode/)
- To bring the site back online

  - The user who has permission to access the site during maintenance mode can
    able to login using **login page**
  - Go to admin/config/development/maintenance and uncheck **Put site into maintenance mode** and save it.

Answer (score 1):

double check that you have done the changes

[Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!maintenance-page.tpl.php/7)

And copied the file into your themefolder?

There is also the option of using maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php
when the db is off.

Answer (score 1):

If clearing your cache doesn't work, you can explicitly set the template in the [preprocess.](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/7)

```
     template_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
      if (isset($variables['db_is_active']) && !$variables['db_is_active']) {
    // Dead databases will show error messages so supplying this template will
    // allow themers to override the page and the content completely.
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'maintenance_page__offline';
      }
      else {
    // Default maintenance template
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'maintenance_page';
      }
    }
```